# How do code coverage tools work in different languages?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, code-coverage

Most established languages have solid test coverage tools available for them, but the depth of functionality differs significantly from one to another.

Also, all the various VMs and compilers have such heterogeneous structure that writing a code coverage tool must be a very different job in C than in Lisp, for example.

- Python has `sys.settrace` to tell you directly which lines are executing
- [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/) (for Java) uses its own compiler and adds debug metadata (last time I used it, anyway)
- [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) (for Java) has a ClassLoader which re-writes bytecode on the fly
- [COVER](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/code/testing/cover/0.html) (for Lisp) has an annotation pass to instrument the code

I'm interested in the implementation of code coverage for different languages:

1. What are the main approaches to get to [C0](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov#l15) coverage, where you can track which lines of code have been executed? I mention native VM introspection and static and dynamic code instrumentation above - are there other methods?
2. Getting to more enlightened coverage data, like [C1 or C2](http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?rcov#l15), seems like a language agnostic task compared with C0. Is smacks of big [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) manipulation to me; are there best practices on how to actually do it? Do more modern logic techniques like [fuzziness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) play a role?
3. A much overlooked aspect of test coverage is displaying the results back to the programmer, which gets increasingly hard with C1 and C2 data. Frankly, although they get the job done for C0, I'm underwhelmed by most test coverage interfaces; what novel and intuitive interfaces have you seen for coverage data?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for here, is it how code coverage work on a low level where you basicly sample the pc (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) and then maps the results towards your source code??? or is it something else he is looking for?

Comment: Interesting.. so sampling the PC is how (most) coverage tools work for languages which compile to native code. That's only one approach to get C0, however, and I'm interested in techniques which work for other languages. In addition to the second and third questions in the original question.

Comment: Most code coverage tools do not use PC sampling, since it's not exact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially all code coverage tools instrument the code in order to check which parts of the code were executed.

As defined in the link you provided, C0 and C1 are pretty similar from the point of view of the person writing the instrumentation. The only difference is where you place the code. I'll go further to speculate that C1 is even easier than C0, because the instrumentation happens on the, let's say, abstract syntax level, where line ends do not count very much.

Another reason I'm saying C1 is easier is because it deals with syntactic entities as opposed to lexical entities: how would you instrument:

```
if
c > 1 && c
< 10
then
blabla
end
```

Well, just a thought.

As for C2, I have never seen it done in practice. The reason is that you can get an exponential blowup:

```
if c1 then * else * end
if c2 then * else * end
...
if cn then * else * end
```

For n lines of code, you would need 2^n tests. Also, what do you do for loops? Typically, you abstract them away as simple if statements (i.e. for each loop you test that its body was executed 0 times for one test and at least once in another test).

I believe sampling the PC is a particularly terrible way to do code coverage because you may miss some statements because they executed too fast :D Same goes for fuzzy logic, which is used to reason about approximations; typically you want your code coverage to b deterministic.

Karnaugh maps are used for minimizing boolean functions, and I do not see any useful link with code coverage tools.

Also, your question is not being very clear at times: do you want techniques to achieve better code coverage or is it just the implementation of code coverage tools that interests you?

Comment: Thanks; interesting point about C0/C1. The reason I mention Karnaugh maps is that if you're attempting C2, they seemed the most obvious way of expressing all the possible paths through conditionals - obviously the minterm generation aspect of K-maps is irrelevant here.

Comment: +1 for "as for C2, I have never seen it done in practice". I heard about C2, thought it seemed like a great idea, and was searching for a tool which could actually do it, until I read this. Thanks for saving me from wasting time!

Answer (score 0):

One method that works with virtually every language is to insert instrumentation
using a program transformation system.

A technical paper found here:
http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf
explains how this can be done in general.

My company, Semantic Designs offers, a large set of test coverage tools
that provide what is called C1 coverage above (e.g, "Branch coverage")
so yes it *is* commonly done), for different languages
(C, C++, C#, Java, COBOL, PHP, all in multiple
dialects).
See www.semdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/index.html

Answer (score -2):

In .NET, the preferred way is to use the [.NET Profiling API](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2003/Internals/Profiling.htm#ProfilingAPI), which basically offers a bunch of joint points in the CLR itself.